# Observer being added after postNotification ONLY on iPhone 4S

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsnotificationcenter, iphone-4

I have a fully functional code that works perfectly on iOS >8.0 for iPhones >5 and all iPads, where I pass information and call function via Observers/Notifications, but on iPhone 4S it just doesn't work.

Through debugging, I actually found out that **ONLY** while running on iPhone 4S the observer gets added **AFTER** the notification gets posted.

This is happening on devices and on the simulator, on iOS 8 and 9, respectively.

Code:

```
**PostNotification**
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.registerCells()

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent

    self.collectionView.delaysContentTouches = false

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "footerUpdateContentSize:", name: "footerUpdateContentSize", object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "seasonUpdateContentSize:", name: "seasonUpdateContentSize", object: nil)

    self.loadDetailTVShow()
}

func registerCells()
{
    self.collectionView.registerClass(HeaderDetailSeriesCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "HeaderDetailSeriesCell")
    self.collectionView.registerClass(FooterDetailSeriesCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "FooterDetailSeriesCell")
    self.collectionView.registerClass(SeriesSeasonContentCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "SeriesSeasonContentCell")
}


func loadDetailTVShow()
{
    let id: String! = (tvShow != nil) ? tvShow!.id! : episode!.seriesId!

    ContentsClient().getContentById(id!).then { data -> Void in
        let m: TVShow? = data as! TVShow?
        self.tvShow = m!
        self.collectionView.reloadData()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("loadedTvShowlist", object: self.tvShow)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0, options: .TransitionNone, animations:
            {
                self.loadingView.alpha = 0.0

            }, completion:nil)
    }
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("SeriesSeasonContentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let seriesContent = cell as! SeriesSeasonContentCell

    seriesContent.seriesContentCell?.tvShow = self.tvShow

    seriesContent.contentView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: width, height: heightSeason)
    seriesContent.seriesContentCell?.view.frame = seriesContent.contentView.frame
}

**Observer**

class SeriesSeasonContent

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.registerCells()

    seasonSelectedIndex = 0

    collectionView.reloadData()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "loadedTvShowlist:", name: "loadedTvShowlist", object: nil)
}

func registerCells ()
{
    self.seasonCollection.registerClass(SeasonViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "SeasonViewCell")

    self.collectionView.registerClass(EpisodeViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "EpisodeViewCell")
}

func loadedTvShowlist(notification : NSNotification){
    self.tvShow = notification.object! as? TVShow

    if (tvShow?.seasons != nil && tvShow?.seasons?.count > 0)
    {
        self.currentSeason = ((tvShow?.seasons!.objectAtIndex(seasonSelectedIndex) as? Season)?.episodes)!

        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        self.seasonCollection.reloadData()
    }
}
```

**Obs: Im using multiple collectionviews in the same view, and the nib files are named correctly**

Is there any reason why the iPhone 4S does load the viewDidLoad method after the notification has been posted?

Comment: Verify that your notification is being posted in main thread on the offending platforms. That block (`ContentsClient().getContentById(id!).then {` seems to be a data fetch callback and you are doing all sorts of UI inside it too.

Comment: Yea, it is being posted on the main thread, thats what makes it even wierder. That is a data fetch call back, but im using the PromiseKit pod that handles these request and only when the request has ended the .then block gets executed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve my problem. The iphone 4s screen size wasn't big enough to trigger the cellForIndex event and the class/observer wasn't initiated until the phone screen scrolled down.